# Format numbers correctly in php

Tags: php, number-formatting

I am trying to format `2176` as `21.76` in php

I have this code:  `$Payment->amount equals 2176 in this example.`

```
$<?php echo number_format($Payment->amount,'2')/100; ?>
```

I get `0.02` Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`number_format($Payment->amount,'2')` gives you string `'2'`, then you divide it by `100`, so the result is `0.02`.

It should be:

```
$<?php echo number_format($Payment->amount / 100, 2); ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to do the division *before* you format the number:

```
$<?php echo number_format($Payment->amount/100,'2'); ?>
```